# What is CSI stand for in CBS.log

Tags: windows

Every run the sfc.exe /scannow in elevated command prompt , in the dir: C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log will  record running log , like this:

> 2021-05-11 09:35:22, Info                  CSI    00000003 IAdvancedInstallerAwareStore_ResolvePendingTransactions (call 1) (flags = 00000004, progress = NULL, phase = 0, pdwDisposition = @0x26e25fdd30
> 2021-05-11 09:35:22, Info                  CSI    00000004 Poqexec successfully registered in [l:12 ml:13]'SetupExecute'
> 2021-05-11 09:35:22, Info                  CSI    00000005 CSI Store 1675774653648 initialized
> 2021-05-11 09:35:29, Info                  CSI    00000006 [SR] Verifying 100 components
> 2021-05-11 09:35:29, Info                  CSI    00000007 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction

What is CSI stand for in CBS.log and CSI Store?
What is [SR] meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSI = Component Servicing Infrastructure
This is part of the so-called Core componentization services (which define the component based architecture introduced with Windows Vista) and takes care of the actual installation of Windows components. It uses the Component Store for that (you know, the %windir%\WinSxS directory).

Greetz,
Pedro

Comment: Oh, almost forgotten: I think SR stands for System Repair. Some CSI entries are [SR], but other types exist, like (F)